# Capacitance per centimeter

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, rf, power-electronics, wireless

I need to design a 1 pF interdigital capacitor for a MMIC design, so I am using an online calculator to find out the dimensions ( https://www.rfwireless-world.com/calculators/interdigital-capacitor-calculator.html), there is also an easy formula for that. Everything is straightforward but the final capacitance out of the formula and the online calculator is Pico Farad per cm, whereas I am asked for a 1 pF capacitor. So, I wonder do I need to consider that per cm here when I am designing it and get rid of it or should I assume to design a 1 pF capacitor means 1 pF/cm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *So, I wonder do I need to consider that per cm here when I am
> designing it and get rid of it or should I assume to design a 1pf
> capacitor means 1pf/cm.*

It's likely that the math behind the calculator is approximating the interdigital capacitance by straightening out the interleaved fingers and treating the "problem" as a 2D problem i.e. it is working out the capacitance between two parallel planar electrodes such as in this [QuickField article](https://quickfield.com/advanced/interdigital_capacitor.htm) on calculating interdigital capacitance: -

[image]

So, when the wireless world calculator talks about capacitance per cm, the "per cm" refers to the length of the line snaking through the mid position between the two electrodes in the picture above.